# Post,Put web Api method returns response code 405 from Angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Firstly, i have read and tried all the similar topics to this and it hasn't solved my problem.
i have and Angularjs application that makes an api call to a c# back-end.

the factory part of my application looks like this

```
 return $http({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                data: {
                    bookedDate: customer.choiceDate,
                    bookedTime: customer.choiceTime,
                    couponCode: customer.couponcode,
                    firstName: customer.firstName,
                    lastName: customer.lastName,
                    userName: customer.choiceName,
                    emailAddress: customer.emailAddress,
                    phoneNumber: customer.choicePhoneNumber,
                    customerAddress: customer.choiceAddress,
                    food: customer.Food,
                    merchantName: customer.merchantName,
                    merchantEmailAddress: customer.merchantEmailAddress,
                    merchantOfficeAddress: customer.merchantOfficeAddress,
                    merchantPhoneNumber: customer.merchantPhoneNumber
                }
            });
```

and the controller method looks like this

```
       [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public bool Post(BookingDto customer)
    {

       bool status = false;

       return status;
    }
```

now the web.config file looks like this:

```
   <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
     path="*."
     verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     modules="IsapiModule"
     scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
     responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
```

and this works for the POST API call on both fiddler and the Angularjs application, but when i execute a PUT, they both fail.
i researched on this and then added

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

and then both PUT and POST works on fiddler but neither works on the Angularjs part.
and finally when i change the Content-Type of the Angularjs to

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
```

i get a 200 ok response for POST from the Angularjs but it doesen't hit the debugger break point but if i remove the data part of the Angularjs request i.e

```
 data: {
                    bookedDate: customer.choiceDate,
                    bookedTime: customer.choiceTime,
                    couponCode: customer.couponcode,
                    firstName: customer.firstName,
                    lastName: customer.lastName,
                    userName: customer.choiceName,
                    emailAddress: customer.emailAddress,
                    phoneNumber: customer.choicePhoneNumber,
                    customerAddress: customer.choiceAddress,
                    food: customer.Food,
                    merchantName: customer.merchantName,
                    merchantEmailAddress: customer.merchantEmailAddress,
                    merchantOfficeAddress: customer.merchantOfficeAddress,
                    merchantPhoneNumber: customer.merchantPhoneNumber
                }
```

it hits the break point of the debugger.

Please can anyone help me out to solve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you put `[HttpPut]` on your `Post(...)` action? Do you have anything that handles `Put` requests in your controller?

Comment: Nothing happens even then, it still dosen't hit.